how to add image in superset dashboard?
I would like to insert an image into the text space within the superset dashboard, but even if I create it like this, the image will not be uploaded.
here is code:
<img src="{{Image URL}}" width="{{Width}}" height="{{Height}}"> 


error image
code reference

How do i add image in my superset dashboard. I would like to upload the image to the dashboard normally.
